# Using Linq to group, order and concatenate strings

Tags: vb.net, linq

Suppose I have the following data

```
Key    ID      Data
A      1       Hello
A      2       World
B      2       Bar
B      1       Foo
```

I am looking to produce the result

```
A     HelloWorld
B     FooBar
```

I am struggling to get the syntax quite right - I was trying to use Aggregate, but I wasn't sure if I could (or should) use SelectMany

I'd be grateful of any help.

```
    Dim data = result.Rows.
                    GroupBy(Function(r) r.Key).
                    Select(Function(g) g.OrderBy(Function(s) s.ID)).
                    Aggregate(New StringBuilder, Function(cur, nxt)                   
                              cur.Append(nxt.First.Data))
```

Thanks

Simon

Comment: Would you put your code u reached so far?

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that you want the words of the same key joined together in the order of their IDs?

Comment: result is a `DataTable`?

Comment: @Matt - yes, @Magnus - I don't mind, @Pr0fess0rX - I've included the code, I'll update it to C# in  a min

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this (C#) should work:

```
var data = from r in result.Rows
           group r by r.Item("Key").ToString() into g
           select new {
               g.Key, 
               Joined = string.Join("", g.OrderBy(s => s.Item("ID"))
                                         .Select(s => s.Item("Data")))
           };
```

Comment: I am working with this (and/or @Bala R)s, but it makes no reference to the Data column. What is string.Join acting on or is it done implicitly in some way?

Comment: @Simon Woods: Sorry about that. I edited my answer to include the Data column.

Comment: Brilliant ... thx. This may not be the place but, given its complexity (imv) is there any benefit in this over, say, writing it procedurally and then wrapping it up in a function?

Comment: Hi is there a VB.NET equivalent for this?

Comment: @Unomono: I'm sure there is. I don't know VB.NET all that well, but you can see if this works for you: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: @SimonWoods: Sorry, for some reason I didn't notice your other comment until now. There's nothing to prevent you from wrapping this query itself, or various parts of it, in methods, in order to break it down into simpler chunks. If you try writing this procedurally, though, you'll find that the code is far more complex: you'll be creating and populating dictionaries and lists, running through `for` loops and `if` statements all over the place. This is the sort of use case where LINQ really shines.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim result = result.Rows.GroupBy(Function(r) r.Key).Select(Function(g) New With { _
    g.Key, _
    String.Join("", g.OrderBy(Function(r) r.ID)) _
})
```

Comment: ah, i just noticed the other answer with it pretty much the same thing. I'll leave mine out because it's vb.net and it's using the method syntax (as in the question).

Comment: u saved me!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative implementation:

```
var source = new Item[]
{
    new Item { Key = "A", ID = 1, Data = "Hello" },
    new Item { Key = "A", ID = 2, Data = "World" },
    new Item { Key = "B", ID = 2, Data = "Bar" },
    new Item { Key = "B", ID = 1, Data = "Foo" }
};

var results = source
    .GroupBy(item => item.Key)
    .Select(group => group
        .OrderBy(item => item.ID)
        .Aggregate(new Item(), (result, item) =>
            {
                result.Key = item.Key;
                result.Data += item.Data;
                return result;
            }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to Aggregate the groups.  You want to aggregage the elements of each group unto itself.

If you want the query to do it, then

```
Dim data = result.Rows
   .GroupBy( )
   .Select(Function(g) g
     .OrderBy( )
     .Aggregate( )
   )
```

If that anonymous function starts getting too hairy to write, just make a method that accepts an `IGrouping<int, Row>` and turns it into what you want.  Then call it like:

```
Dim data = result.Rows
   .GroupBy( )
   .Select( myMethod )
```